# How to disable the next element(textarea) on click of nearest element(Checkbox) in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of Check box, i want **the next nearest** Text area to get disabled.

Following is snippet:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="fRegistrer" name="fRegistrer" id="fRegistrer">
</div>

<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
  <textarea cols="200" rows="5" class="normal" name="kommenter" id="kommenter"></textarea>
</div>
```

in Jquery:

```
 onclick="$(this).closest('.textnormal').find('textarea').attr('disabled',true)"
```

Comment: where is check box in your html code here?

Comment: Sorry. Just corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click of the checkbox you can use `closest()` to get the parent `div`, `next()` to find the next sibling `div`, then `find()` to get the contained `textarea`. Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('textarea').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="fRegistrer" name="fRegistrer" id="fRegistrer">
</div>

<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
  <textarea cols="200" rows="5" class="normal" name="kommenter" id="kommenter" disabled="true">Foo bar</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check whether it fits wholly my scenario :p

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fRegistrer').click(function () {
    debugger
    $(this).parent('.pure-u-1').next().find('#kommenter').attr('disabled',true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/we7be5w0/)**